# Mouse click not recognised after Nvidia driver install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, mouse, display-resolution

Background: iMac, late 2009, 24", GeForce 9400 256MB RAM. I am using the default drivers with a 16.10 upgrade from a 16.04 installation. I plugged in various second monitors and they all have a flicker on them even at low resolution and low refresh rate.

So I did 

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot -n`

Nvidia created /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Both displays are now working fine at maximum resolution but mouse clicks are generally not being recognised. Problems are no clicks in the desktop area are being recognised, neither are tabs in a browser and application windows cannot be dragged. There might be other problems but these are enough to make me purge the drivers.

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Does anybody have any ideas as to how to have the Nvidia drivers running and get the mouse clicks?

Comment: It turns out that installing nvidia-current does not guarantee that the correct driver gets installed. I did <code>lspci -vnn | grep VGA</code> and then looked up the correct driver on the Nvidia site. The 304 driver instead of the 340 driver had been installed and so it was as simple as <code>sudo apt-get install nvidia-340</code> as I had already purged the previous driver install.

Comment: You can post it as an answer to your question, that may help others. Otherwise the question will be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue from installing Nvidea-current and nvidea-settings.
Following up on the comment by Op, I did the following and it fixed my issue

First I did the following command to see what model GPU I had

```
$ sudo lshw -C display  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GF108 [GeForce GT 630]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:39 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

From that I went to Nvideas driver page and using the manual driver search and that info I downloaded their .run installer file.

After restarting I ran

```
$ chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.12.run
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.12.run -x
$ cd NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.12
$ sudo ./nvidia-installer -XZqaq --no-x-check
```

Restarted display service

```
$ sudo service gdm3 restart
```

And my mouse problems, and previous display problems, were fixed.

Answering this question with more detailed answers so this question doesn't get  pruned.